# Как преобразовать unix в нормальную дату в Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, jinja2

**Привет всем, есть вопрос как преобразовать ***Unix*** в нормальную дату в Django и вывести в шаблон.**

База данных удаленная ***MySQL*** оттуда подтягиваю данные.

Есть такое поле в котором хранится весь список ***Unix*** времен

[image: Поле из БД MySQk]

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы это всё преобразовать и вывести в шаблон.

Пример **Unix** времен на сайте нужно чтобы была нормальная дата.

[image: Пример времен.]

Comment: А по русски Вы не могли бы вопрос задать? А то я вот не понимаю, как ОС Unix можно во что-то преобразовать :-(  И я не понимаю, что такое "нормальная дата"? И я не понимаю, а что в Django есть свои, какие-то особые даты?

Answer (score 0):

Предполагая, что `obj` содержит объект модели:

`date = datetime.fromtimestamp(obj.created)` создаст переменную с python `datetime` объект из вашего Unix-времени в колонке `created`.

`print(date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))` напечатает в консоль время в переменной `date` в формате `ММ/ДД/ГГГГ, ЧЧ:ММ:СС`. Больше информации по форматам можете найти [тут](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime).

Пример полного кода в вашей view функции:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.fromtimestamp(obj.created)
print(date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

Если это будет использоваться более одного раза, то я бы посоветовал добавить метод для вашей модели:

```
def get_verbose_time(self): # Не забудьте про импорт в начале файла
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(obj.created)
    print(date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

Так-же хотелось бы отметить, что в `Django` для этого есть специальный класс `models.DateTimeField`, который вы могли бы использовать вместо вашего `models.IntegerField`. Больше информации о `models.DateTimeField` [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField). Данный класс возвращает вам `datetime` объект, производя конвертацию автоматически.